# Basic Select with Laravel Eloquent do not work

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have 2 table: `User` & `Demands`. Inside the table `Demands`, I have the `user_id` as a foreign key. 
The User log in with a name (which I have throught the Session).
What I want to do is:
  - Have the name of the User (his log in)-> since I do not have the session implemented, I write the name directly inside the code.
  - Search his ID thanks to his name.
  - Search all of his demands with his id.

```
  $name = "Jason";
  $UserID = User::select('id')->where('name', '=', $name)->get();
  $User= User::find($UserID);
  $demands = Demand::where('user_id', '=', $UserID)->get();
  echo $demands;
```

My array is then empty. But inside my database, I do have 3 demands of this user_id...

Do you guys have any clue please ?

Cordially.

Comment: Why are you selecting the just the ID then doing another query to get the whole row? Why not just get the whole row from the first query? `User::where('name', '=', $name)->first();`

Comment: You should set up some proper Eloquent relationships, which would make getting the user's demands as easy as `$user->demands`.

Comment: I do have this into the User model: return $this->hasMany('App\Demands');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everyone else is right that the first query returns a collection. But you're doing an extra query that is not needed here. This can be simplified to query the users table only once.

```
$name = "Jason";
$User = User::where('name', '=', $name)->first();
//$User= User::find($UserID); remove this as it is not needed.

if(!$User) {
    return "User not found";
}

$demands = Demand::where('user_id', '=', $User->id)->get();
echo $demands;
```

Comment: You're right !
I changed Jason to another name which is in the database and has an demands.  But I've an error: `Trying to get property 'id' of non-object` at this line `$demands = Demand::where('user_id', '=', $User->id)->get();`

Comment: You should add a check after the query like `if($User) {}` to make sure a user if found and return an error if it's not. Alternatively you can use `firstOrFail();` and Laravel will automatically return a 404. Since the user isn't being found, but you say it does exist, check the case and make sure there aren't any spaces or anything like that.

Comment: I don't know why I've this error... I just copy/paste the name, nothing more or nothing less.

Comment: I'm using the `$demands` after, so if I put it into a `if`, I could not use it after

Comment: If you don't find a user, then you can't even get the demands so you should return an error instead of continuing.

Answer (score 1):

`get` function is returning a Eloquent Collection insteed value. You must want to use the `first` function. This function will return the first row of the query.

```
 $name = "Jason";
  $UserID = User::select('id')->where('name', '=', $name)->first();
  $User= User::find($UserID);
  $demands = Demand::where('user_id', '=', $UserID->id)->get();
  echo $demands;
```

Answer (score 1):

`$UserID` is a collection, not an integer. Try this:

```
$name = "Jason";
$user = User::select('id')->where('name', '=', $name)->first();
$User= User::find($user->id);
$demands = Demand::where('user_id', '=', $User->id)->get();
echo $demands;
```

Answer (score 1):

Please change

```
$UserID = User::select('id')->where('name', '=', $name)->get();
```

to

```
$UserID = User::select('id')->where('name', '=', $name)->first()->id;
```

Comment: Even easier: `User::whereName($name)->value('id')`.

Comment: If I want to search something else than the name ? Like the student number.

Comment: @IsmaElzem Same approach. `whereStudentId(12345)` will search the `student_id` column for `12345`.

Answer (score 0):

Since the user is logged in it means he's authenticated. 
Try this

```
$UserID = Auth::user()->id;

$demands = Demand::where('user_id', '=', $UserID);

echo $demands;
```